# Is there a addon for VS Code that add a value slide controller and 2D array value picker?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have recently started to learn to code shaders in GLSL from the website https://thebookofshaders.com. On the website there is a code editor and a canvas so you can see the shader changes live when you change the code. In this editor there is a function where you can click on a value and change it with a slider and if you click on an 2D array you can choose the value on a graph.

Example: https://thebookofshaders.com/07/

I want to code in my own environment on VS Code but I can't seem to find any setting or add-on that does this.

Comment: just clone the website to a `WebView` in an extension

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=circledev.glsl-canvas